# Adobe PDF Links Problem in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, acrobat

I created a link in a pdf document to a local html file ressource.

When you press the link, the following messagebox is shown:

[image]

For none German speakers... Securitywarning ... Document is trying to open ressource... are u sure that you wanna do that... Options are "Ok" or "Block"

But it is independent if click "block" or "ok", the effect is still the same ... nothing happens... the target isn't called.

In IE Version < 8 all works fine. Also in FF or other browsers. So it seems to be a IE8 specific problem.

- IE Version: 8.0.6001.18702 / IE Zone is MyComputer
- Acrobat Reader 8.1.0 (same effect on adobe reader 9.x)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

The best solution would be to supress this warning completely ... or at least get it to work with this warning hehe.

I already setted the intranet zone security to low, but this changes nothing :(

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Oh come on there has to be a solution to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/Acrobat/9.0/Standard/WS981E9B4B-F8E4-4511-ADE4-2D7380472979.html

It looks like an Acrobat warning, not an Internet Explorer one... Do other browsers on your system open this document in Acrobat as well?

Comment: As stated in the question, the error only shows up in IE8. So, in any other browser, the file works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments on [this page](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrobat/2009/03/acrobat_91_and_reader_91_avail.html) from back in April when Acrobat 9.1 came out I recall someone had issues with links opening from Reader to IE8. (Search the page for the surname "Subasinghe".) - but my hazy reccolection is that it was fixed with version 9.2. I note that you specified testing on 9.x though, so this is probably not of any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Are you viewing the pdf in Reader or within IE8?

Is your IE8 version 8.0.6001? IF so, you may be experiencing [this](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/509385?tstart=0), and getting the very latest IE8 might fix it.